# Remove all regex coincidence in a string

Tags: c#, string, replace

Given a string like this:

> [Order Data]\r\n Contract Number=7654321\r\n
> Order Number=00\r\n Contract Order=1234567\r\n Country=Poland\r\n
> Location=whatever\r\n Ship Date=YYYY/MM/DD\r\n...

I want to replace the value between the equals "=" and the new line "\r\n" in each line.

> [Order Data]\r\n Contract Number=\r\n
> Order Number=\r\n Contract Order=\r\n Country=\r\n
> Location=\r\n Ship Date=\r\n...

I have tried with something like this.

```
string[] stringSeparator= new string[] { "\r\n" };
List<string> diff;

IEnumerable<string> set1 = 
    file.Split(stringSeparator, StringSplitOptions.None).Distinct();
            
var cleanLines= new List<string>();

foreach (var set in set1) {
    var index = set.IndexOf("=");
    if (index >= 0)
    {
        var input = set.Substring(0, index+1);
        list.Add(input);
    }
    else {
        list.Add(set);
    }
}
```

The problem with that solution is that i can not repeat lines to add to the list, so i'm missing in the result some repeated lines after remove the value that come in the file.

Answer (score 0):

This code will take your example data and convert it into your example output:

```cs
// example data
var input = "[Order Data]\r\n Contract Number=7654321\r\n Order Number=00\r\n Contract Order=1234567\r\n Country=Poland\r\n Location=whatever\r\n Ship Date=YYYY/MM/DD\r\n";

// remove the values
var output = new Regex(@"=[^\r]+\r").Replace(input, "=\r");

// show the answer
MessageBox.Show(output.Replace("\r", "\\r").Replace("\n", "\\n"));
```

The replacements on that last line are just so you can see the `\r` and `\n` characters.

The end result is:

[image]

Which would render as:

```
[Order Data]
 Contract Number=
 Order Number=
 Contract Order=
 Country=
 Location=
 Ship Date=
```

Comment: Thanks, i really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a simple Regex.Replace

```
var input = "[Order Data]\r\n Contract Number=7654321\r\n Order Number=00\r\n Contract Order=1234567\r\n Country=Poland\r\n Location=whatever\r\n Ship Date=YYYY/MM/DD\r\n";
//Matches = followed by any character except \r. Replace with group 1 (=)
var cleaned = Regex.Replace(input, @"(=)[^\r]+", "$1", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Output

> [Order Data]   Contract Number=   Order Number=   Contract Order=
> Country=   Location=   Ship Date=

Comment: Thanks, i really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can match the first occurrence of an equals sign and match 1 or more times any following character using `=.+`

In the replacement use an equals sign.

```
string str = "[Order Data]\r\n Contract Number=7654321\r\n Order Number=00\r\n Contract Order=1234567\r\n Country=Poland\r\n Location=whatever\r\n Ship Date=YYYY/MM/DD\r\n";
string result = Regex.Replace(str, "=.+", "=");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Output

```
[Order Data]
 Contract Number=
 Order Number=
 Contract Order=
 Country=
 Location=
 Ship Date=
```

See a [C# demo](https://ideone.com/qG07e3).